# Vuejs text fields sometimes not editable, after refresh it working normally

Tags: vue.js, inertiajs

hello my project is laravel project, that use ineritaljs as frontend middleware. and text fields binded to to data() functions variables.

```
  <div class="form--group">
<label for="order_details_fname">Recipient’s FirstName *</label>
 <input
    id="order_details_fname"
    type="text"
    class="form--controll"
     v-model="order_data.first_name"
/>

<div class="form--group">
<label for=""
    >Recipient’s Last Name *</label>
<input
    id="order_details_lname"
    type="text"
    class="form--controll"
    v-model="order_data.last_name"/>
                                                       
 </div>
```

data function

```
  data() {
       
            return {
                order_data:{
                    /** */
                    first_name:null,
                    last_name:null,
              /** */
            },
          }
         },
```

sometimes fields not editable, (just like read-only fileds) is anyone know solutions for this?

Comment: There's nothing in the code you have shared that would suggest and elements would be disabled/read-only, can you add the whole component's code?. When you inspect an input while it's disabled to you see ```disabled``` added in the element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi all i just found issue for this. its not  vuejs issue, but in a npm package (vue-range-slider) . it register global events to capture input. i'm still wandering why package owner not trying to fix it.
anyway if anyone had this kind of issue please check

https://github.com/xwpongithub/vue-range-slider/issues/18

https://github.com/xwpongithub/vue-range-slider/issues/21

thank you all. peace